# Installing Pip in Wrong Location

Tags: package-management, python3, pip

I am using Ubuntu LTS 14.04 right now, and I could not install the last version of pip3 in my operating system. Someone told me that the last version is not supported in 14.04, and I can install the version 9.0.2. After that he gave me a installation command: `python3 get-pip.py pip==9.0.2 --user`

After executing this command, I assumed that pip is installed into the system, but pip3 commands do not work. When I write pip3/pip --version, the message "pip is not installed" occurs. The weird thing is the fact that I tried to install pip using the command `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` after using this command `python3 get-pip.py pip==9.0.2 --user` , and I faced the message "you have already pip version 9.0.2."

What is the problem in this point ? Both I cannot use pip and install it.

Extra Knowledge: I found some pip folders in the directory: `~/.local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall it completely and install it again with the command you have been told to.

Uninstalling: `sudo apt-get purge python3-pip`